# Can not load configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a large project, I have to load internal dependency but getting the exception that can not load the configuration class. I have already used the base package name with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz"})` annotation but application fails to load the context. Here is the ExceptionInterceptorAutoConfiguration class that's been imported as maven dependency in the project.

```
@Configuration
public class ExceptionInterceptorAutoConfiguration {
public ExceptionInterceptorAutoConfiguration() {
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({DefaultExceptionInterceptor.class})
public DefaultExceptionInterceptor defaultExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new DefaultExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({HystrixRuntimeException.class, HystrixExceptionInterceptor.class})
public HystrixExceptionInterceptor hystrixRuntimeExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new HystrixExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({ServiceExceptionV2Interceptor.class})
public ServiceExceptionV2Interceptor serviceExceptionV2Interceptor() {
    return new ServiceExceptionV2Interceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({FacadeExceptionV2Interceptor.class})
public FacadeExceptionV2Interceptor facadeExceptionV2Interceptor() {
    return new FacadeExceptionV2Interceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({ServiceExceptionInterceptor.class})
public ServiceExceptionInterceptor serviceExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new ServiceExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({FacadeExceptionInterceptor.class})
public FacadeExceptionInterceptor facadeExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new FacadeExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionInterceptor.class})
public MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionInterceptor methodArgumentNotValidExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({MethodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionInterceptor.class})
public MethodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionInterceptor methodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new MethodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionInterceptor() {
    };

}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass({ServletRequestBindingExceptionInterceptor.class})
public ServletRequestBindingExceptionInterceptor servletRequestBindingExceptionInterceptor() {
    return new ServletRequestBindingExceptionInterceptor() {
    };
}
```

}

Below is the exception that I am getting Any help in this regard.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.xyz.commons.sdk.logging.autoconfigure.ExceptionInterceptorAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:127) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at com.xyz.consumer.dispute.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotation(Executable.java:570) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.isAnnotationPresent(AccessibleObject.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:617) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:33) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.isMatch(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:420) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you post the class `ExceptionInterceptorAutoConfiguration` ?

Comment: @KedarJoshi updated the question with the required class

Comment: Check this thread for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352967/spring-boot-errorjava-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-typenotp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem previously I had created the resource tab under source/java and it was failing. Can you check on that just a wild guess.