# Getting java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, pom.xml

Getting below

```
> **java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy**
```

exception while running application.

Is it related to configuration or any other particular issue?

Can anybody please explain/correct me, for what i'm facing this issue/exception?

Help will be really appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ngen.cosys</groupId>
    <artifactId>expbu</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ExpBU</name>
    <description>Export Build Up</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/..</main.basedir>
        <coverage-format>html</coverage-format>

        <sonar.host.url>http://172.18.151.72:9000</sonar.host.url>

        <sonar.pitest.mode>reuseReport</sonar.pitest.mode>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>

        <sonar.exclusions>**/*generated*/**, target/**, **/*model*/**, **/*config*/**, **/*enums*/**, **/*constant*/**, **/*dao*/**, **/*filter*/**</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>
            <url>http://172.18.151.71:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-activemq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot error:java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352967/spring-boot-errorjava-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-typenotp)

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer I tried, above post answers are not working for me.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I updated the latest Maven Configuration Credentials in **settings.xml**

Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352967/spring-boot-errorjava-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-typenotp) provides a detailed explanation of why this error is occurring, while you can refer to this post for more details - for the time being, you could add this to your `pom.xml` to resolve your issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!