# Spring BeanCreationError: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Is there a way to tell which dependency/annotation is missing in case of this exception?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

I'm using spring-boot `1.5.17.RELEASE` and spring-cloud `Edgware.SR5`, as per start.spring.io. I have spring-boot-starter-web, spring-cloud-starter-config and spring-cloud-starter-eureka included. It's a simple jar that's supposed to be deployed on WildFly alongside Keycloak 4.5.0.Final to register it in Netflix's Eureka instance.

Comment: The thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352967/spring-boot-errorjava-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-typenotp looks discussing similar issue.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of threads reference similar issue, but I've observed that the solutions are always different.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that solution to that problem is always different. Mine was to exclude `spring-webmvc` from `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency that I've already had:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```