# After upgrade springboot from 2.1 to 2.2, shows CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

My application is using mongodb.
I upgraded spring boot from 2.0 to 2.1.18, my application worked very well.
Then I upgraded it from 2.1.18 to 2.2.13, it showed CannotGetJdbcConnectionException.
I checked a lot of questions, seems there is no solution.
Is there anybody can help me, please.....

This is the log

```
2021-07-01 18:41:12.136 DEBUG 27811 --- [           main] o.s.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers    : FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@5149f008 failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer.analyze(HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer.java:29)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:35)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:816)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:801)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at jp.co.XXX.XXX.XXXApplication.main(XXXApplication.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

    ... 10 common frames omitted

2021-07-01 18:41:12.144 ERROR 27811 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [jp.co.XXX.XXX.XXXApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
```

Here is my dependencies

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.13.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    // SpringBoot
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')

    // Security
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    // Database
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')

    // session
    compile('com.whalin:Memcached-Java-Client:3.0.2')
    compile('io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0')
    compile('de.javakaffee.msm:memcached-session-manager-tc8:2.1.1')
    compile('net.spy:spymemcached:2.12.3')

    // Template
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:2.3.0")

    // Apache Common
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.6')
    compile('commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6')

    // http client
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0')
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.23.0')
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-xml:1.23.0')

    // Use swagger-java-client Library
    compile('io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.8')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5')
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3')

    // Other
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16')
    compile('net.arnx:jsonic:1.3.10')
    compile('com.ibm.icu:icu4j:62.1')
    compile('com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3')

  

    // Model Mapper
    compile ('org.modelmapper:modelmapper:0.7.5')
    
    // Test
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3')
    testCompile('junit-addons:junit-addons:1.4')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19')
    testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2')
    testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2')
    testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2')
    testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-classloading-base:1.6.2')
    testCompile('org.easymock:easymock:2.4')
    testCompile('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.7.1')
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == "org.apache.tomcat.embed") {
            details.useVersion "9.0.41"
        }
    }
}

clean.dependsOn customClean
```

I tried to run with debug mode, it showed nothing but "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

````
09:31:04.236 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Calculate task graph'
09:31:04.236 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Calculate task graph' completed
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'run' not found in root project 'XXX'.
09:31:04.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
09:31:04.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 0s
09:31:04.238 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
09:31:04.238 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 13: released lock on root.1
09:31:04.239 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
09:31:04.239 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run build' completed```
````

Comment: Please add your dependencies (your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`) to the question.

Comment: Thank you @Deinum, I modified my question, and added my dependencies

Comment: There is nothing JDBC related in your dependencies, so it is actually weird that it is even trying to configure Hikari. Is there something containing a JDBC driver or is there something in your config triggering this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Since it worked properly using springBoot 2.0.2 and springBoot 2.1.18. It just happened when  I upgraded it to 2.2.13. I changed nothing but the springBootVersion to  2.2.13.RELEASE

Comment: Try running with `--debug` or `debug=true` that way you can see what matches are positive.

Comment: I tried, it showed nothing but "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception." and I pasted the debug result in the question.

Comment: That is a totally different exception/error during your build?

Comment: It showed nothing. I tried to debug the ```TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy ``` class according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416012/12029020, and I found the problem. seems it's because of  the following dependency ```implementation('io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0')```. I added ```implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'``` , problem solved.  And seems ```compile``` has been deprecated since gradle 4.7, so I changed it to ```implementation```

Comment: Hmm why would you need an additional dependency. That is weird. One thing is that `'io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0` is pretty old and is for Spring Boot 1.5 so you might need to upgrade that as well (as that might be pulling in old dependencies which aren't compatible!).

Comment: Yes, that's true. I upgraded it to be ```io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter:2.2.8.RELEASE```, but it seems it still need me to add ```implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'``` So I'll just keep it..... thank you so much @Deinum!!!!

Comment: Which is too new as that is for Spring Boot 2.3 and not 2.2 leading again to the same issue, if that dependency was needed the library itself should pull it in. You should check all your dependencies for compatibility not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.

I tried to set breakpoint at `TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` class.

Just found it's because we have dependency named `io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter`, in it's ConditionalOnRefreshScope.java, it needs to import the following classes `import org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration;`
`import org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope;`
I added  `implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context', version: '2.2.8.RELEASE'` problem solved.

Comment: I doubt that that is the real solution, but rather a workaround bringing in newer dependencies which appear to fix the problem. As mentioned in the comment the version of the memcache starter is for Spring Boot 1.5 not 2.2, so I would suggest reverting your change and upgrade that dependency as well (you need compatible dependencies else things will break).

Comment: @Deinum, yes, I quite agree with you. I reverted my changes, and upgraded ```io.sixhours:memcached-spring-boot-starter``` to v2.2.0, but it still needs to ```import org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration```

Comment: I also tried to revert springBoot to 2.1.18.RELEASE, I fount when I run the application , it will also have that exception, but it won't stop my application ```2021-07-02 16:40:00.447 DEBUG 44335 --- [           main] c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor : Failed to introspect meta-annotations on interface io.sixhours.memcached.cache.ConditionalOnRefreshScope: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

Comment: That isn't an error but a debug (thus informational) message.

Comment: ```That isn't an error but a debug (thus informational) message``` yes, so I mean it might be springboot's changes,like in 2.1it will be considered as an info, but in 2.2 it'll be treated as error... there is no document to proof it though.... I'm trying to upgrade other dependencies